# How to detect when a file has been uploaded?

Tags: uploads, media-library, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to analyze a file after it has been uploaded using a custom file upload field ([ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/file/)).

Is there a way to do this using a hook?
If not using a hook then maybe theres a Javascript event?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? "Analyze" in what way? For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The ACF documentation says, the native upload of WordPress is triggered, so you can use [`wp_handle_upload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload):

```
function my_cool_func() {
    // whatever it is that you want to do, do it here
} // function my_cool_func
add_action('wp_handle_upload', 'my_cool_func');
```

Or maybe you want/have to hook into [`add_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_attachment)...